# Laravel pagination not working with group by clause

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-pagination

It seems Laravel pagination does not working properly with group by clause. For example:

```
$users = Subject::select(DB::raw('subjects.*, count(user_subjects.id) as total_users'))
            ->join('user_subjects', 'user_subjects.subject_id', '=', 'subjects.id')
            ->whereNull('user_subjects.deleted_at')
            ->groupBy('subjects.id')
            ->orderBy('subjects.updated_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(25);
```

**Produced**

```
select subjects.*, count(user_subjects.id) as total_users 
from `subjects` inner join `user_subjects` on `user_subjects`.`subject_id` = `subjects`.`id` 
where `subjects`.`deleted_at` is null and `user_subjects`.`deleted_at` is null 
group by `subjects`.`id` 
order by `subjects`.`updated_at` desc
```

note that, there is no `limit` clause on the query.

**Working fine if no group by clause in the query:**

```
$users = Subject::select(DB::raw('subjects.*, count(user_subjects.id) as total_users'))
            ->join('user_subjects', 'user_subjects.subject_id', '=', 'subjects.id')
            ->whereNull('user_subjects.deleted_at')
            ->orderBy('subjects.updated_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate(25);
```

**produced the following query:**

```
select subjects.*, count(user_subjects.id) as total_users from `subjects` 
inner join `user_subjects` on `user_subjects`.`subject_id` = `subjects`.`id`
where `subjects`.`deleted_at` is null and `user_subjects`.`deleted_at` is null 
order by `subjects`.`updated_at` desc 
limit 25 offset 0
```

does anyone has any idea how can i fix this?

Comment: Not sure why but with groupBy the paginator can't handle this in Laravel. It is basically retrieving whole set and on the PHP side slices the result. It's better for you in this case to do it manually or get the count you need differently.

Comment: The above is true - if you look into the code you'll see that the paginator will try to add `LIMIT`s when it can, but as soon as a query has a `GROUP BY` it goes into a mode whereby it has to get all results and do the pagination manually in PHP using `array_slice`. I was once looking around the paginator classes and actually thought it was a bug that the paginator didn't use `LIMIT`s but then realised that was only when it's a `GROUP BY` statement. So yeah - you'll find that the paginator should be working fine, just inefficiently. I just hope you don't have a huge result set!

Comment: @alexrussell thank you. The problem is we have large data set :(.

Comment: Then unfortunately doing you own pagination appears to be the only way.

Answer (score 12):

Check the documentation
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/pagination

> Currently, pagination operations that use a `groupBy` statement cannot
>   be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a `groupBy` with
>   a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database
>   and create a paginator manually.

Answer (score 1):

I know it is an old question, by I am sharing my solution for future reference.

I managed to write a function based on [this link](https://blog.hashvel.com/posts/laravel-custom-pagination/) which does the heavy job of determining the pagination of a complex query. Just pass the 'QueryBuilder' and it will return the paginated object/collection.

Additionally, this procedure can track and maintain the other parameters except for `page=`.

```
public function mergeQueryPaginate(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query): \Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator
    {
        $raw_query = $query;
        $totalCount = $raw_query->get()->count();

        $perPage = request('per-page', 10);
        $page = request('page', 1);
        $skip = $perPage * ($page - 1);
        $raw_query = $raw_query->take($perPage)->skip($skip);

        $parameters = request()->getQueryString();
        $parameters = preg_replace('/&page(=[^&]*)?|^page(=[^&]*)?&?/', '', $parameters);
        $path = url(request()->getPathInfo() . '?' . $parameters);

        $rows = $raw_query->get();

        $paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator($rows, $totalCount, $perPage, $page);
        $paginator = $paginator->withPath($path);
        return $paginator;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

This works for me in laravel 5.2

```
Select(\DB::RAW("assignment_descendant_child.assignment_descendant_child_id, assignment_descendant_child.assignment_descendant_child_name, COUNT(assignment_descendant.assignment_descendant_id) as xNum"))
            ->leftJoin(
                'assignment_descendant',
                'assignment_descendant.assignment_descendant_child_id',
                '=',
                'assignment_descendant_child.assignment_descendant_child_id'
            )
            ->orderBy('assignment_descendant_child_name')
            ->groupBy('assignment_descendant_child.assignment_descendant_child_id')
            ->paginate(\Config::get('constants.paginate_org_index'))
```

Answer (score -1):

1. create a database `view` named`vw_anything`. MySql query will be like

   `create view vw_anything as select subjects.*, count(user_subjects.id) as total_users from subjects inner join user_subjects on user_subjects.subject_id = subjects.id 
   where` `subjects`.`deleted_at is null and user_subjects`.`deleted_at is null group by` `subjects`.`id`;
2. Now create a new model named **UserSubModel** for this view, `protected $table = 'vw_anything';`
3. Now your paginate query will be like `UserSubModel::orderBy('subjects.updated_at', 'desc')->paginate(25);`

.

To answer this questioin [Laravel Pagination group by year and month only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55330139/laravel-pagination-group-by-year-and-month-only)

View query will be :

```
create view vw_anything as select gallery.*, DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m") as tanggal,count(created_at) as jumlah from gallery group by tanggal;
```

Let you model is VwModel then your paginate query will be

```
VwModel::where('type','Foto')->orderBy('tanggal','desc')->paginate(2);
```

Answer (score -2):

This works if you want to group by and paginate.

```
$code = DB::table('sources')
    ->select(DB::raw('sources.id_code,sources.title,avg(point) point'))
    ->join('rating','sources.id_code','rating.id_code')
    ->groupBy('sources.id_code')
    ->groupBy('sources.title')
    ->groupBy('sources.language')
    ->groupBy('sources.visited')
    ->paginate(5);
```