# Laravel Pagination group by year and month only

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want to make paginate from laravel, group by year and month only
when i used get , it work well

```
$data = DB::table('gallery')
        ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m") as tanggal,count(created_at) as jumlah'),'gallery.*')
        ->where('type','Foto')
        ->groupBy('tanggal')
        ->orderBy('tanggal','desc')
        ->get();
```

but when i use paginate , there is an error :
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tanggal' in 'group statement' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `gallery` where `type` = Foto group by `tanggal`)

```
$data = DB::table('gallery')
        ->select(DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%Y-%m") as tanggal,count(created_at) as jumlah'),'gallery.*')
        ->where('type','Foto')
        ->groupBy('tanggal')
        ->orderBy('tanggal','desc')
        ->paginate(2);
```

Or any idea for group by just year and month laravel 5.4?

Comment: See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55334691/1887301

Answer (score 0):

From https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination

> Currently, pagination operations that use a groupBy statement cannot be executed efficiently by Laravel. If you need to use a groupBy with a paginated result set, it is recommended that you query the database and create a paginator manually.

Here's an alternative solution provided on [Jen's Segers's blog](https://jenssegers.com/57/laravel-pagination-with-grouping-and-eager-loading)

Comment: oke thanks, but i used for other alternatives with add field just year and month in database